# I'm trying to upload a discord bot to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I need help. I get a discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'

code error:

```
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510053+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2022-11-05 18:39:19] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command play
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510080+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510087+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 190, in wrapped
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510087+00:00 app[worker.1]:     ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510088+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/botOld.py", line 434, in play
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510088+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await queue_module(ctx, False)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510089+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/botOld.py", line 50, in queue_module
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510091+00:00 app[worker.1]:     voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", source=url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)) #executable="/Exeyarkius/blob/main/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", source
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510091+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 289, in __init__
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510091+00:00 app[worker.1]:     super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510092+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 166, in __init__
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510092+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510092+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 180, in _spawn_process
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510093+00:00 app[worker.1]:     process = subprocess.Popen(args, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW, **subprocess_kwargs)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510093+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510094+00:00 app[worker.1]:     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510094+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1847, in _execute_child
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510095+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510095+00:00 app[worker.1]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510096+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510096+00:00 app[worker.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510096+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510096+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510097+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510097+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510097+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 986, in invoke
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510098+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510098+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 199, in wrapped
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510098+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2022-11-05T18:39:19.510099+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'
```

I uploaded the buildpacks, I also uploaded my project to github and am trying to run ffmpeg.exe

code line:

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe", source=url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
```

I will be glad to every answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overlow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: And please always include the _full_ error message, including traceback. You are just showing the very last line.

Comment: Why are you pointing to `/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe` instead of just `ffmpeg`? And why do you use an `.exe` extension at all? Heroku doesn't run Windows.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I changed from `/app/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe ` on `ffmpeg` and it worked, but it didn't play music. The application logs simply write `discord.player: ffmpeg process 12 successfully terminated with return code of -11.`

Comment: That's a different question.